# Default class for form elements

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a custom form class that extends base `Zend_Form` and specifies the decorators for the form itself and elements as well.

And now I'm in stuck - how to add some particular HTML class to every input element?

The only thing I could think of is to override `addElement()` but I'm open to better solutions if any.

Comment: Did you try a `get_class_methods($formObject)` to see if there were any other methods available which may address your request?

Comment: @Mike Purcell: I currently look at the `Zend_Form` sources and cannot get idea what could help me.

Comment: What do you mean with "particular class"? HTML class attribute?

Comment: @Adrian World: yep. Will clarify this in the question

Comment: just another solution `class My_Form extends Zend_Form
{

    public function render(Zend_View_Interface $view = null)
    {
        
        foreach ($this->getElements() as $element) {
              $element->setAttrib('class', 'default');
        }
        
        return parent::render($view);
    }`

Comment: @b.b3rn4rd: yep. Similar to mine thoughts. Also check if form has already been rendered could be nice. And put it as an answer - it deserves an upvote.

Comment: thanks, I guess there aren't many ways of doing this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just another solution:

```
class My_Form extends Zend_Form
{ 
    public function render(Zend_View_Interface $view = null) 
    { 
        foreach ($this->getElements() as $element) { 
            $element->setAttrib('class', 'default'); 
        }

        return parent::render($view); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (!$this->_getIsRendered())` around this method body could save some CPU

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you want a way to automatically assign a unique class to each element.

Expanding on the answer given by **b.b3rn4rd**, try something like:

```
class My_Form extends Zend_Form
{ 
    public function render(Zend_View_Interface $view = null) 
    { 
        foreach ($this->getElements() as $element) { 
            //assign the class as some unique identifier that is part of the element
            //each element requires a unique name so it's a good place to start
            $element->setAttrib('class', $element->getName()); 
        }

        return parent::render($view); 
}
```

}

Comment: Yep. Personally I overrode `addEelement` and added a check if `class` already exists (to not lost already added classes). But not sure why you think I need unique class. I need the same class applied to a lot of elements, that is what `class` in html for ;-)

Comment: @zerkms wasn't sure what you wanted exactly so I took a stab. Glad you found your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like solutions that inherit Zend_Form, so I devised another way to do this.

```
<?php

abstract class Application_Style
{

    private $_object;


    function __construct ($object = null)
    {
        if (isset ($object))
        {
            $this->apply ($object);
        }
    }


    function apply ($object)
    {
        $this->setObject ($object);
        if ($this->filter ())
        {
            $this->onApply ();
        }

        return $object;
    }


    function __call ($method, $arguments)
    {
        return call_user_func_array (array (
            $this->getObject (),
            $method
        ), $arguments);
    }


    abstract protected function onApply ();


    protected function filter ()
    {
        return true;
    }


    function setObject ($_object)
    {
        $this->_object = $_object;
    }


    function getObject ()
    {
        return $this->_object;
    }
}




class Application_Style_ElementClass extends Application_Style
{


    function onApply ()
    {
        foreach ($this->getObject ()
            ->getElements () as $element)
        {
            $element->setOptions (array (
                'class' => 'test-class'
            ));
        }
    }


    function filter ()
    {
        return $this->getObject () instanceof Zend_Form;
    }
}


$form = new Zend_Form ();
$form->addElement ('text', 'name');
new Application_Style_ElementClass ($form);  // apply the class name
echo $form;
```

This way you can apply all the styles needed for any form in any order.

Comment: You probably wanted to implement a strategy pattern. Constructor that does all the work is something wrong. Additionally I think that `$this->getObject ()` is overkill. Within one inheritance tree there is nothing wrong in reading and writing directly to the properties.

Comment: You can be right about all this, but this is a blueprint. You can ignore the solution completely if you don't like it.

Comment: I do like it as an alternative ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Adding HTML class attributes to elements is like this

```
$element->setAttrib('class', 'text'):
or directly 
$element->class = 'text;
```

Comment: if he has 500 elements with all the same class name certainly not but then you don't even need a class to begin with

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer the question. I **do know** how to set class. And the question was "how to add some particular HTML class to every input element?" in automatic fashion